# Logging with OmniAuth and Devise RoR 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am following the docs from here [LINK](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

This is `Users::OmniAuthCallbacksController` `facebook` method:

```
def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
        logger.debug "YES"
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
        logger.debug "No"
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    end
end
```

This is part of 'application.html.erb' view

```
<h1><%=user_signed_in? %></h1>
```

If I try to login with Facebook it creates new row in `users` table for this user, it works, but I see `user_signed_in?` is `false`.
What I need to do to authenticate with Devise and OmniAuth ?

Comment: If you are using the confirmable module you need to set `@user.confirmed_at = Time.now` before saving.

Comment: Hi, thx it works in your way, but now email is confirmed without confirmation. What can I do in this case ?

Comment: If I use in the model `user.skip_confirmation!` it works, too. Please, add your question to mark it as answer.

Comment: Its pretty much exactly what `.skip_confirmation!` does. You can answer the question yourself. I don't really need rep